# Grails app won't create new log on server

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am trying to create 4 different logs to write to (using Tomcat). Here is the code (There is some odd stuff because I'm experimenting with it):

```
log4j = {

    appenders {
        rollingFile  name:'infoLog', file:'/logs/info.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
        rollingFile  name:'warnLog', file:'/logs/warn.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN
        rollingFile  name:'errorLog', file:'/logs/error.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR
        rollingFile name:'debugLog', file:'/logs/debug.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG
    }
    root {
        info 'infoLog', 'errorLog', 'warnLog', 'debugLog'
        error 'errorLog'
        warn 'warnLog'
        debug 'debugLog'        
    }

    info 'grails.app'
    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    warn   'org.mortbay.log'
    debug 'grails.app'
}
```

When I deploy and run the app, I get this in catalina.out:

> log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/info.log (No such file or
>   directory)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:177)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:102)...

(I get that same message for each log I'm trying to create). Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular error message probably means either that the `/logs` directory does not exist or that it is not writeable by the user ID that your Grails app is running under.

But more generally, your root logger definition is wrong, you just need one log level (the level you want to use by default for loggers where you don't specify a more precise rule) attached to all the appenders, e.g.

```
root {
    error 'infoLog', 'errorLog', 'warnLog', 'debugLog'
}
```

The thresholds of the various appenders will ensure that each gets the right messages: with this configuration `debugLog` will receive all messages (debug, info, warn and error); `infoLog` will receive info, warn and error; `warnLog` will receive warn and error; and `errorLog` will receive only error messages.

Comment: I had actually had it working but didn't realize it, but you were right on your observation. It actually will only log debug and lower if you put dubug 'infoLog', 'errorLog', etc... but thanks for the tip, put me on the right track.

Comment: @js3v you should specify in the `root` section whatever log level you want to use for classes that don't have a specific level assigned below.  A root level of `error` plus a `debug 'grails.app'` _will_ send `grails.app.anything` debug messages to the `debugLog`.